# Entering the BIOS breaks GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I have dual boot Ubuntu/Windows 10 on my Acer laptop. UEFI system.
I've just figured out that when I simply enter the BIOS settings by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> at start (without changing or saving anything), or also when entering the BOOT MENU settings by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> at start, then GRUB permanently disappears and instead Windows 10 loads. After this, GRUB must be reinstalled from a Live CD or by reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch.

How is this possible???

Comment: The only thing i can imagine is that you have a problem with buggy firmware. Try to update UEFI/BIOS to latest version if available.

Comment: I already updated the BIOS to the latest version, before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Contact Acer support at https://www.acer.com/

Comment: When you exit are you resetting to defaults? Acer requires you to enable supervisory password & set trust on the grub/ubuntu .efi boot files. You may be losing those entries as it reverts to defaults. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like buggy firmware. Check for an update on Acer's site. (It will probably be called a "BIOS update" or something similar, although if the computer was sold any times since late 2011, it's more likely to be an EFI/UEFI than a BIOS.)

If there's no firmware update, or if applying it doesn't help, then you should complain -- loudly -- to Acer, since this is a serious bug. Beyond complaining, there are better workarounds than what you're using:

- **`fbx64.efi`** -- Recently, Ubuntu has begun shipping this EFI program file and installing it in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` (from Ubuntu). I have yet to study this file in detail, but it's intended to work around the sort of problem you're describing. To work automatically, you'd probably want to copy it to `/boot/efi/EFI/bootx64.efi` (from Ubuntu), but it may require explicit configuration beyond that, and I haven't yet looked into that detail. Also, this might not really do anything by itself if your computer boots straight to Windows. Thus, you might want to focus on the next solution....
- **Fix the boot entries** -- One or both of two NVRAM-based EFI settings are being changed: The `BootOrder` variable holds the boot order, and `Boot####` entries (where `####` is a hexadecimal value) hold pointers to specific boot loaders. If the `BootOrder` alone is being changed, you can fix it with various tools, like `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu or `bcdedit` in Windows. Since you're booting straight to Windows after such an incident, the easiest fix is likely to be to use the third-party [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) tool, which enables you to adjust the `BootOrder` variable in a simple GUI list. Even if the `Boot####` entry for Ubuntu is being deleted, you can use EasyUEFI or `bcdedit` to create a new entry that points to `EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`. Typing `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"` in an Administrator Command Prompt window should fix the problem with `bcdedit`; or you can do the equivalent in EasyUEFI.

This is just one example of what I call a *boot coup.* See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) for more on this subject. (That page is part of my rEFInd documentation, but the principles apply to other boot loaders.)